# Format the ouput of df command without newlines

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I have a script running that establishes a remote SSH Tunnel and runs the following code to to check for available disk space and gets formatted with AWK and reports back as:

```
#!/bin/bash
for DATA in $(sudo df -h | grep -E '/$|/var$|/tmp$' | awk '{print $1","$5","$6}' | tr -d '%')
    do
        DISK=$(echo $DATA | awk -F, '{print $1}')
        FREE=$(echo $DATA | awk -F, '{print $2}')
        MOUNT=$(echo $DATA | awk -F, '{print $3}')
        if [[ "$FREE" -ge '90' ]]
            then
                echo "$HOST does not have enough room to patch, \"$MOUNT\" ($DISK) is ${FREE}% full"
        fi
    done
```

> I have purposefully removed the required escaping to make this run
> properly on a remote shell (for readability)

This runs fine, except when the line is too long and df cuts the output across lines, like this:

[image: Green text Linux terminal showing the output of the df -h command]

That messes up the for loop and returns bad data.  I'd like any advice on how to format that newline out. I have tried several things with sed/tr/printf, and I have referenced these two printf cheatsheets:

- https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet
- https://notgnoshi.github.io/printf/

I have referenced other posts with similar titles and already tried to export COLUMNS, but that didn't appear to do anything.

I appreciate the feedback, thank you.

## Edit:  df (GNU coreutils) 8.4

Comment: what version of df is this? The GNU coreutils implementation doesn't seem to have this issue although busybox does. the obvious approach to reformatting is to note that continued lines don't have enough fields and that continuation lines start with whitespace

Comment: df (GNU coreutils) 8.4

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with some textual sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df -h | awk '
    NF == 1 {device = $1; getline; $0 = device $0}
    {sub(/%/, "", $5); print $1 "," $5 "," $6}
'
```

The first line of the awk body will see if the current line only has 1 field. If yes, remember the device, read the next line, and insert the device in the (new) current line.

This should output, for the item you highlighted:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_01-lv_var,16,/var
```

And you can remove grep and tr from your pipeline.

---

Your shell loop needs a lot of improvement. Rather than get into that, you can just to all the work in awk:

```
df -h | awk -v host="$HOST" -v limit=90 '
    BEGIN {msg = "%s does not have enough room to patch, \"%s\" (%s) is %s full\n"}
    NR == 1 {next}
    NF == 1 {device = $1; getline; $0 = device $0}
    $5 >= limit {printf msg, host, $6, $1, $5}
'
```

Comment: The AWK statement you provided in place of my for loop worked very well, thank you!  As I'm always looking to improve my coding abilities, could you please share what about the for loop needs improvement?  Either here, or in a DM.  Thank you.

Comment: Essentially: 1) paste your code into http://shellcheck.net 2) don't use ALLCAPS variable names, and 3) read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Great thanks! I've been using shellcheck.net for years.  Always used CAPS for variables and CamelCase for functions.  I've preferred arrays to while loops, but that's just me.  I appreciate the feedback, thank you!